# Timing of Synchronous/Asynchronous Bus Operation

Tags: computer-architecture

What is difference between Synchronous and Asynchronous Bus Operations. And how are they change in read cycle and write cycle ??
I shared a website it tells these bus operations bu I didint understand clearly and I didint understand these pictures in the website.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-synchronous-and-an-asynchronous-bus

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Could you please add *to the question text* exactly what you did not comprehend in the linked article?

Comment: I actually did not understand what is difference between Synchronous and Asynchronous bus operations. And this link tells it 2 pictures. I did not understand these pictures.

Comment: *synchronous* timing is clock-driven. *asynchronous* timing doesn't have a clock.